# FluentValidation - Transform optionals to underlying type?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Say I have this midel

```cs
class Model
{
    public Optional<string> Str { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to map the optional field so that rules are ignored when the optional is empty and allied otherwise?
E.g. when `HasValue` is true - apply all the chained validation, when `HasValue` is false - ignore all the chained validation.

```cs
class MyValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    MyValidator()
    {
        RuleForEx(x => x.Opt) // see below
            .NotNull(); // apply string rules, not Optional<string> rules
    }

    // Is it possible to implement something like this?
    private IRuleBuilderInitial<Model, string> RuleForEx(Expression<Func<T, Optional<string>>> expression)
    {
        return Transform(expression, x => x.HasValue : x.Value ? `[no idea what is here]`);
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like an extension method named `RuleForOptional(x => x.Opt)` would be possible, which returns a rule builder object for the `T` in `Optional<T>`.

Comment: Does `RuleFor(x => x.Opt.Value).NotNull().When(x => x.Opt.HasValue);` not work? I'm also questioning the use of an optional here in a view model.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, judging by the implementation of `Optional<T>` it will thrown an exception if there is no value and `Value` is accessed without a check for `HasValue`, but it's an Expression, not just Func, so maybe this approach will work. The reason for this is my laziness - I want to reuse the existing validations and don't want to write my own

Comment: The `When(...)` gets executed before calling the getter. But, I understand your laziness :)

Comment: Maybe create a class called `OptionalRuleBuilder<T, TProperty>` that implements `IRuleBuilderInitial<T, TProperty>`? Then create a common parent class for your validators with a `RuleForOptional` method?